# Equivalent of perl diamond/python fileinput in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am looking for a function or operator (maybe a library) that mimics [perl's diamond operator](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node68.html) or [python's fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html).

Of course I could check myself for arguments, make sure each is a file and loop through, if none exists read from stdin...but that defeats a purpose: to create small unix command line scripts in seconds that needs to loop through files or stdin like cat, grep, sed etc. Not having to write 30 lines boilerplate code...just one or two lines.

Comment: args.each {
    new File(it).eachLine { line -> println(line) }
}

Comment: Thansk for your tips. It is good enough for quick and dirty scripts  but it doesn't automatically revert to stdin (guess I can check that with if-statement before) and more importantly it doesn't handle stuff behind automatically (e.g. FileNotFoundException). I was really good though so I will definitely use it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not such a built-in function/library.

Anyway, if your objective is to make scripts and loop through files or stdin, you can create something similar as a groovy lib. For example:

*FileInput.groovy*:

```
class FileInput {
    static void input(String[] args, Closure c) {
        if (args) {
            args.collect { new File(it) }.findAll { it.isFile() }.each { it.eachLine(c) }
        } else {
            System.in.eachLine(c)
        }   
    }
}
```

Then you compile the above and place the resulting classes under `~/.groovy/lib`:

```
$ groovyc -d ~/.groovy/lib FileInput.groovy
```

And then you can use it in your scripts

*test.groovy*

```
import FileInput

FileInput.input(args) { println it.toUpperCase() }
```

So that

```
$ groovy test.groovy example.txt
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
LINE THREE
```

Defaults to *stdin* when there is no file:

```
$ groovy test.groovy < example.txt
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
LINE THREE

$ cat example.txt | groovy test.groovy
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
LINE THREE

$ groovy test.groovy
hello
HELLO
world
WORLD
```

Skips dirs:

```
$ groovy test.groovy example.txt testDir
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
LINE THREE
```

And right now (since it is testing `isFile()`) is also disregarding not existing files:

```
$ groovy test.groovy example.txt wrongFile.txt example.txt
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
LINE THREE
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
LINE THREE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def inputs=[];
```

Only practical way is to have collection "similar objects".  In this case having a collection of InputStream would do

```
if(args.length==0)
{
    inputs.add(System.in)
}
else  {
    args.each {
        inputs.add(new FileInputStream(it))    
    }
}

inputs.each {
    (it).eachLine { line -> println(line) }
}
```